# building netcdf on linux

Tags: curl, netcdf

I am following the tutorial here:

https://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/netcdf/docs/getting_and_building_netcdf.html

I built HDF5, ZLIB, and CURL from source. When I compile netcdf:

```
CPPFLAGS=-I${H5DIR}/include LDFLAGS=-L${H5DIR}/lib ./configure --prefix=${NCDIR}
```

and then run

```
make check
```

I get:

> curl/curl.h: No such file or directory.

I build curl though, how do I get it to see it?

Comment: If you also built CURL from source, you probably have to add CURLs `include` and `lib` paths to the `CPPFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a configure bug that has been fixed in master and will be in the next release of netCDF (4.6.2). It should check for curl.h in configure, not error out at build time. ;-)

The workaround is to include the curl include and lib directories in your CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS.

```
CPPFLAGS='-I${H5DIR}/include -I/location/curl/include' LDFLAGS='-L${H5DIR}/lib -L/location/curl/lib' ./configure --prefix=${NCDIR}
```

Note that I have added single-quotes around the CPPFLAGS and LDFLAGS values, so that we can include multiple locations with spaces between them.